# Subtracting a diagonal matrix from an ill-conditioned one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, python, machine-precision

I've written Python 3 + NumPy code where I perform the following calculation:

$$(B - \lambda I)^{-1}$$

where $B$ is a symmetric negative semidefinite matrix where some elements can be huge (greater than `1e25`). When subtracting the diagonal matrix, floating-point does not have enough precision to perform the operation. Is there any matrix decomposition or trick that overcomes this problem?

The only solution I see now is rewriting the package using a different library with more precision than NumPy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you need to invert the matrix? What is the size of the square matrix to be inverted?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It can be any size, righ now I'm testing with 64x64

Comment: What about its entries? Integers? Rationals?

Comment: At which step in your algorithm does the loss of accuracy occur? If it's in finding the inverse, then this might be salvageable by using a better matrix inverse algorithm. If your program has already lost accuracy by the time it's formed $B - \lambda I$, then the problem is nothing to do with matrices, since the accuracy is being lost *in each entry*.

Comment: If the eigenvalues of $B$ are significantly larger than $\lambda$ then you could just use the Taylor series $(B - \lambda I)^{-1} = B^{-1} + \lambda (B^{-1})^2 + \lambda^2 (B^{-1})^3 + \cdots$.  But as you say $B$ is ill-conditioned I'm guessing it contains both small and large eigenvalues.